# Apache logs showing CONNECT request to server that isn't mine

Tags: security, http, hostname

I've just installed an ELK stack on my server and I'm noticing something strange whilst watching the APM (at least I think it is strange, anyway). My Laravel application is continuously getting a CONNECT request from the same `remote_address` to `account-public-service-prod03.ol.epicgames.com`. Why is my server receiving this when this isn't my hostname? Is this something I should be worried about?

[image]

Comment: It is strange, maybe your public IP belonged to epicgames before and they have a zombie entry in one of their DNS servers or another DNS hasn't been updated. Or, way more likely, someone is trying to DNS spoof some host and has given your IP address. You could try to reverse lookup your public IP, e.g. here: https://remote.12dt.com/lookup.php and find out if it's a public entry or just a mistake/attack.

Comment: The domain belongs to next-gen.ro and hitting the IP directly redirects me to a router login page. Can that help us determine the nature of the connection attempt?

Comment: Welcome to the Internet.

Answer (score 2):

As [@NuTTyX](https://serverfault.com/users/236608/nuttyx) mentions, `CONNECT` requests are usually indicative that someone is attempting to use your server as a proxy.

You should check in your webserver logs to ascertain what status code is being returned for these requests. A `200` response will indicate that your server is likely an open web proxy that will quickly get your address added to numerous blacklists.

Answer (score 1):

A CONNECT request could mean that somebody is using your server as an (open) proxy to navigate.

Do you have mod_proxy enabled? Unless you need it (for an inverse proxy configuration or any other intended use) I would recommend to disable it completely.